# Changing data in collection does not save

Tags: laravel, collections

I am trying to add foods attributes in this collection :

```
   $days = $days->each(function($day) use($orderedDays, $order) {

      $foods = collect($day->foods)->map(function(&$food, $keys) use($day, $orderedDays, $order){

        if(in_array($day['id'], $orderedDays)) {

          $item = OrderItem::where('order_id', $order->id)->where('meal_plan_day_id', $day['id'])->first();

          $qty = $item->qty;
          $food->qty = $qty;
          return $food;

        } else {
          $food->qty = 0;
          return $food;
        }

      });

    });
```

My problem is that the $food->qty is not saved, when I dump in map :

```
                    "food_name": "test",
                    "final_price": 51000,
                    "max_no_order": 1,
                    "extra_no_price": 51000,
                    "qty" :2
```

But out of each it not saved

Comment: You are assigning the `$food` variable in your first closure, but you don't do anything with the variable. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes you are right, I do not know how do that, because $food is in $days and I want all of them, @Jerodev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the map function on `$days` as well if you want to modify the data and in this function, return the modified `$days` variable.

```
$days = $days->map(function ($day) use ($orderedDays, $order) {

    $day->foods = collect($day->foods)->map(function ($food, $keys) use ($day, $orderedDays, $order) {

        if (in_array($day['id'], $orderedDays)) 
        {
            $item = OrderItem::where('order_id', $order->id)->where('meal_plan_day_id', $day['id'])->first();

            $qty = $item->qty;
            $food->qty = $qty;
        } 
        else
        {
            $food->qty = 0;
        }

        return $food;

    });

    return $day;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must assigning that array value by reference. With "&$variable".

```
$days = $days->each(function($day) use($orderedDays, $order) {

  $foods = collect($day->foods)->map(function(&$food, $keys) use($day, $orderedDays, $order){

    if(in_array($day['id'], $orderedDays)) {

      $item = OrderItem::where('order_id', $order->id)->where('meal_plan_day_id', $day['id'])->first();

      $qty = $item->qty;
      $food->qty = $qty;
      return $food;

    } else {
      $food->qty = 0;
      return $food;
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result is same